# What is the outcome of an evaluation?

Tags: single-word-requests

As I understand an evaluation is the process. But what is the outcome?

Or is evaluation both, the process and the outcome?

Comment: The *result(s)*? (What kind of evaluation are we talking about, anyway?)

Comment: If you evaluate someone you are performing an evaluation. The result of that is an evaluation. Ain't English grand?

Comment: The outcome could also be the _result_ of the evaluation.

Comment: _Evaluation_ can be used for the outcome as well as the process: _The evaluation was positive_. Also, there is a great deal of individual local practice in the use of such ad hoc terms in business, so it is best to consult an experienced local native speaker.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it is used to refer to both the process and the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Treating "the process" in your question as the thing that's being evaluated, I would answer as follows.

Evaluations can be formative or summative.
 - A formative evaluation is done early in the process and can impact
   the later outcomes of the process.
 - A summative evaluation is done at the end of the process to determine what the results of the process were.  This sense of *evaluation* is sometimes used synonymously with *output*, the measurable results of an outcome.

---

Treating "the process" instead to mean "the act of evaluating," the answer to your question is:

An evaluation can be either the process of evaluating something... 
      *He was busy with the evaluation of his students.* 
...or it can be the result of this process. 
      *The student read the evaluation his teacher gave him*.